# Reading two inputs from the user

Tags: c#, .net, string, console, string-parsing

I would like to get the user enters two different values using only ONE statement of `Console.ReadLine()`.
More specifically, instead of using two different variables declarations with two different `ReadLine()` method - I want to let the user enters two variables at the same time using one `ReadLine()` method for further processing.

Answer (score 7):

Something like this?

```
var line = Console.ReadLine();
var arguments = line.Split(' ');
var arg1 = arguments[0];
var arg2 = arguments[1];
```

In this example, space delimits the arguments. You can use `,` or `;` as a delimiter, if you would like to.

Answer (score 2):

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter values separated by space");
string input = Console.ReadLine();
string[] inputs = input.Split(' ');
foreach (string inp in inputs)
{
     Console.WriteLine(inp);  
}
```